# Can I merge data when sending put request to firebase realtime database using axios?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, merge, axios, put

I am able to update my data in Firebase Realtime Database using axios like this:

```
axios.put('/blogposts/' + postId + '.json', post, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).then(response => {
  res.status(200).send(json.stringify(response.data));
}).catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send('error putting blog post.');
});
```

But the post being put looks like this:

```
{
  title: '...',
  body: '...'
}
```

and the posts in the database look like this:

```
{
  title: '...',
  body: '...',
  createdAt: 123,
  updatedAt: 123
}
```

Before putting the post, I give it an updatedAt stamp:

```
post.updatedAt = Date.now();
```

Then I put the post using the axios call above.

In the database, the post ends up looking like this:

```
{
  title: '...',
  body: '...',
  updatedAt: 123
}
```

createdAt has disappeared.

I'm wondering if there's a config setting that tells Firebase not to overwrite the whole post, but each field one by one, so that title gets overwritten, body gets overwritten, updatedAt gets overwritten, but createdAt is left alone. I believe this is called a merge, but adding merge:true to the config object doesn't do what I want.

Is there a way to do what I want, or does the updated object always have to include each and every field of the old object even if the field isn't being updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge the data you write with the existing data at the location in a REST request, [use the `PATCH` verb](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update). From there comes this example:

> ```
> curl -X PATCH -d '{
>   "nickname": "Alan The Machine"
> }' 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/users/alanisawesome.json'
> ```

In Axios that seems to translate to `axios.patch(...)`.

Comment: Thanks Frank. That's exactly what I was looking for.